# Background-image works in CSS but not JS for Webpack

Tags: webpack

Im using Webpack 3. If I set a background-image in my CSS it works fine:

```
body {
    background: url('./img/1.jpg');
}
```

However when I do the same thing with JavaScript the image doesnt appear on the page and I get an error:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("./img/1.jpg")';

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I think this is because the file loader recognises the image asset in the CSS but not in my JavaScript. Is this correct? If so how do I fix it?

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/script.js',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Swipe time'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got it working but importing the image as a variable.

```
import Image from './img/1.jpg';
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${Image})`;
```